# cakephp3: namespace error with prefix route

Tags: routes, namespaces, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to implement a REST api with cakephp 3.

In order to give an easily reproducible example of my problem, I start with a fresh installation of cakephp 3.1.11.
In config/routes.php, I add:

```
Router::prefix('/api', function ($routes) {
    $routes->fallbacks('DashedRoute');
});
```

If I access `http://mysite/prefixtest/api/Accounts` I get the (expected) "Missing Controller error":

```
Error: AccountsController could not be found.

Error: Create the class AccountsController below in file: src/Controller//Api/AccountsController.php

<?php
namespace App\Controller\\Api;

use App\Controller\AppController;

class AccountsController extends AppController
{

}
```

Notice the double slashes in the path and the double backslashes in the namespace.

Creating the AccountsController in  `src/Controller/Api/AccountsController.php` (single / in the path) with the suggested code results in the error:

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
File src/Controller/Api/AccountsController.php
Line: 2
```

Not too surprising, since the double backslash in the namespace isn't allowed in php. 
Removing the additional backslash gets me back to the "Missing Controller error", probably since the controller is not in the namespace cakephp expects it in.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opposed to scopes or routes, prefixes are not supposed to be connected with a leading slash.

See also **[Cookbook > Routing > Prefix Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#prefix-routing)**

Comment: Ouch! You are absolutely right. Removing the leading slash instantly fixes my problem. Thank you.